# L. Gegenbauer's proof of Infinitude of Primes

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem, prime-gaps

I was going through the paper 'Euclid’S theorem on the infinitude of primes: A historical survey of its proofs' by Romeo Mestrovic where he mentioned that 
L. Gegenbauer proved Infinitude of Primes by means of the series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ n^s}$,(p-$20$) which is the claim of Dickson taken from his book 'History of the theory of numbers, volume I, Divisibility and Primality ' (p-$413$). They both referred to the following paper which I am unable to find from internet.

L. Gegenbauer, Note ¨uber die Anzahl der Primzahlen, Sitzungsber, SBer. Kais. Akad. Wissensch. Wien (Math.) 95, II (1887), 94–96; 97, Abt.IIa (1888), 374–377.

I asked this question in the following [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706681/l-gegenbauers-proof-of-infinitude-of-primes/3706686?noredirect=1#comment7623279_3706686) .

I will be highly grateful if someone explain the proof mentioned in this paper or at least mention the source where I can find it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So now you've asked the question three times today, once here and twice on math.stackexchange. Learning the rules by breaking them is not encouraged.

Comment: I guess if it's not on the internet, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: It was not answered there that is why I asked it here.

Comment: It is very hard to see people are downvoting this question whence it has not been yet answered.

Comment: The custom is to wait for several days, not for a couple of hours, before posting to another site.

Comment: can you please say how long should I wait before posting it in other sites?

Comment: "The custom is to wait for several days". Also, if you do it, you're expected to leave a link at *each* site to the question at the other.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo and links there to related questions.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment)

If it helps, this is cited in Laundau's Handbuch on page 920, as

8. Über Primzahlen. Sitzungsberichte der kaiserlichen Akademie der
   Wissenschaften in Wien, mathematisch -naturwissenschaftliche Classe,
   Bd. 94, Abth. 2, S. 903—910; 1887.
9. Über die Anzahl der Primzahlen. Sitzungsberichte der kaiserlichen
   Akademie der Wissenschaften in Wien, mathematisch-naturwissenschaftliche
   Classe, Bd. 95, Abth. 2, S. 94—96; 1887.

Also, there are a lot of volumes of "Sitzungsberichte der kaiserlichen
Akademie der Wissenschaften in Wien, mathematisch-naturwissenschaftliche
Classe" in the internet archive, but you will have to search one by one since they do not seem to have the correct metadata.